# Kafka - producing to a topic then consuming from that topic later?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit

I'm a former legacy ActiveMQ user learning Kafka. And I have a question.

With Active MQ you can do this:

- Submit 100 messages into a queue
- Wait however long you want
- Consume those 100 messages from that queue. Guaranteed single consumer of the message.

I try in Kafka to do the same thing

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

public class KafkaTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaTest.class);
    public static final String MY_GROUP_ID = "my-group-id";
    public static final String TOPIC = "topic";

    KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));

    @Before
    public void before() {
        kafka.start();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        kafka.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPipes() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafka.getBootstrapServers());
        consumerProps.put("group.id", MY_GROUP_ID);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Future consumerFuture = es.submit(() -> {
            try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps)) {
                consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));
                while (true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                        LOG.info("Thread: {}, Topic: {}, Partition: {}, Offset: {}, key: {}, value: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value().toUpperCase());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Consumer error", e);
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(10000); // NOTICE! if you remove this, the consumer will not receive the messages. because the consumer won't be registered yet before the messages come rolling on in.

        Properties producerProps = new Properties();
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafka.getBootstrapServers());
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        Future producerFuture = es.submit(() -> {
            try (KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerProps)) {
                int counter = 0;

                while (counter <= 100) {
                    System.out.println("Sent " + counter);
                    String msg = "Message " + counter;
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, msg));
                    counter++;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Failed to send message by the producer", e);
            }
        });

        producerFuture.get();
        consumerFuture.get();
    }
}
```

This example does not work if you do not start Consumer, wait for it to start, then run the producer.

Can anyone show me how to alter my example program to do things where the messages await to be consumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your consumer config, you need to add `auto.offset.reset=earliest` or call `seekToBeginning` after subscribing.

Otherwise, it starts to read from the end of the topic. In other words, if you start the consumer after the producer, it'll begin to read after all the existing data.

Comment: let's say you turn 1 week of consumer producer using the seekToBeginning strategy. Then your conumer is restarted. Will it replay the entire week worth of data now because of the seekToBeginning thing?

Comment: oh i see i have to keep track of the current offset in a synchronous manner

Comment: about `auto.offset.reset` from https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html#idm45788273492184 This property controls the behavior of the consumer when it starts reading a partition for which it doesn’t have a committed offset or if the committed offset it has is invalid (usually because the consumer was down for so long that the record with that offset was already aged out of the broker). >>> 
so you have to keep track of some committed offset to prevent your reconnected consumer from replaying the old messages again?

Comment: got it. others who are struggling with that same thing, just read the whole link that i pasted in my previous message. read it from top to bottom.

Comment: Kafka itself keeps track of the committed offsets. If there is no offsets, or you dont commit it, then yes, that setting applies, with the default being `latest`

Comment: Well working for the most part like a charm. But if you look at this test here, I for some reason needed to seekToBeginning even though I had the auto.offset.reset=earliest. Do you know why that is? https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/546d28d65a420f36ff452e5f4722814bf0fec3f7/tika-integration-tests/tika-pipes-kafka-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/tika/pipes/kafka/tests/TikaPipesKafkaTest.java#L174

Comment: ignore me - once again lol. i accidentally hand groupID conflict was causing my test to get weird and throw weird behaviors. once fixing that seems good now

Comment: Ideally, you'd use a random UUID for the group id for tests. Unless explicitly testing offset commits where you need a consistent value

Comment: thanks! will literally do that right now.